# Need to make a link that shows all news after limiting the amount shown in the index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller

In my index view i have limited the amount of news shown to the 2 newest ones

but i also want to include a link to all the news in the db

in my news controller i have

```
def index
    @news = News.all(:order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 2)
end
```

and i made another method to give me all the news

```
def all
  @news_all = News.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
end
```

should i instead limit the amount of posts in the view ?

here is the link i made to show all news

```
<%= link_to 'All News', all_news_path =>
```

and my custum route

```
match "news/all" => "news#all", :as => "all_news"
```

im gettin the error that `NewsController#show` cant find news with `id="all"`

im quite new to ruby and im not sure how to accomplish this :)

**UPDATE**

I updated my code like Kien suggested

used collection in my route

```
resources :news do
  collection do
    get 'all'
  end
end
```

my index link to all news

```
<%= link_to 'All news', all_news_path, :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-success' %>
```

and i have an `all.html.erb` view

```
<% @news_all.each do |news| %>
  <h2><%= news.title %></h2>
  <%= news.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") %><br />
  <%= truncate(news.body, :length => 450) %><%= link_to ' meira', news %>
  <%= news.author %><br />
<% end %>
```

this worked great yesterday, but today i pulled from git and now i get `undefined local variable or method all_news_path` on the link in my index file..

can anyone see why ?

**ROUTES**

```
                       root        /                                               news#index
             all_news_index GET    /news/all(.:format)                             news#all
                 news_index GET    /news(.:format)                                 news#index
                            POST   /news(.:format)                                 news#create
                   new_news GET    /news/new(.:format)                             news#new
                  edit_news GET    /news/:id/edit(.:format)                        news#edit
                       news GET    /news/:id(.:format)                             news#show
                            PUT    /news/:id(.:format)                             news#update
                            DELETE /news/:id(.:format)                             news#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make route like that, it will conflict with `show` route:

```
news/:id
news/all
```

The route will misunderstand `all` is `:id` parameters.

You should use collection:

```
resources news do
  collection do
    get 'all'
  end
end
```

You will get route: `all_news_path`. You also need to make a template `all.html.erb` in your `app/views/news` folder, to display all news.

Is this your typo?  `<%= link_to 'All News', all_news_path =>`

It's should be `<%= link_to 'All News', all_news_path %>`

Comment: Thanks mate! and yeah that was a typo, i also had a twitter bootstrap ` :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-success'` behind it but i left it out to simplify the code guess thats where the `=>` sneeked in :P

Comment: this worked great yesterday but today im getting an `undefined local variable or method all_news_path` error my link looks just like yours and my route too, do you have any idea what could cause rails to not recognize the `all_news_path` ? ill update the post with new code

Comment: maybe in `all` action you don't have a `@news_all`. Or check your routes again, maybe after merge it changes somethings.

Comment: I still have the `@news_all = News.all(:order => "created_at DESC")` in the all method, and my route is the collection you suggested (i only added the : in front of news), is there any way to hardcore the route? im running rake routes now

Comment: i added the routes above and i dont understand the `all_news_index` route, shouldnt it just point to the all page? not the index

Comment: Okey i got it, today it wanted `all_news_index_path` not just i just `all_news_path` that worked yesterday, hope it will work again tomorrow haha thanks for your help mate :)

Comment: I don't understand why it's `all_news_index`, but you have it, so just use `all_news_index_path`, it will work.